# Log Shipping LSN in backup too recent to apply

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-backups, log-shipping

Log shipped has been working. I get the message:

> Error: The log in this backup set begins at LSN 193489000090302900001, which is too recent to apply to the database. An earlier log backup that includes LSN 192973000046320700001 can be restored.

I checked using `Restore HEADERONLY` and found the file that LSN is in and performed:

```
RESTORE LOG MicrosoftDynamicsAX 
FROM DISK = N'F:\RLASQL07\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\MicrosoftDynamicsAX_20170813161501.trn' WITH NORECOVERY;
```

This restored fine but when I rerun the `LSRESTORE` and it fails.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article may be of some use.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2009/08/08/logshipping-secondary-server-is-out-of-sync-and-lsrestore-job-failing/

At this time, to check if there are a gaps in the Restore Process. You can run the query below to try to find out whether a redundant Backup Log was performed :

```
SELECT 
    s.database_name,s.backup_finish_date,y.physical_device_name
FROM 
    msdb..backupset AS s INNER JOIN
    msdb..backupfile AS f ON f.backup_set_id = s.backup_set_id INNER JOIN
    msdb..backupmediaset AS m ON s.media_set_id = m.media_set_id INNER JOIN
    msdb..backupmediafamily AS y ON m.media_set_id = y.media_set_id
WHERE 
    (s.database_name = 'databaseNamePrimaryServer')
ORDER BY 
    s.backup_finish_date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks TT.  We take all of our backups through TSM and rarely have issues but I found that someone took a backdoor backup and it caused a gap in my transaction logs stream so I will have to recreate log shipping I guess.